# Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy - Swift Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to create an alert so when a user signs up and then wants to log back in they can be warned if the password is wrong because at the moment it just performs the segue and the attempt to alert fails. I'm using Firebase so the password that is entered into firebase on sign up should be the one users log in with.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var EmailAddressTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    EmailAddressTextField.delegate = self
    PasswordTextField.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}

@IBAction func LogInButton(_ sender: Any) {
if (EmailAddressTextField.text != "" && PasswordTextField.text != ""){
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: EmailAddressTextField.text!, password: PasswordTextField.text!) { user, error in
    if error == nil {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogInSegue", sender: nil)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter a correct email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to check something with you, as your description above is a little unclear. When you enter the wrong email/password combination, does your app still perform the "LogInSegue" (as well as failing to show the alert)?

If so, it sounds like you might have connected your segue to the UIButton instead of the UIViewController.
To check this, click on your segue in the Storyboard and see if the UIButton is highlighted.
If it is, then delete this segue and follow the instruction below to connect your new segue from the view controller:

[image: Add segue to view controller]

Comment: You're a legend! Thank you, but so annoying that something this trivial was the error!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. Would you mind marking the answer as correct please? Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You are presenting `UIAlertController` on `SignInViewController` so at that time `SignInViewController` is not in navigation stack.

So when you are presenting `UIAlertController` at that time check the `self.navigationController?.viewControllers` and verify that it is in stack or not.

for eg.

```
//check before self.presnt...
print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)
```

So you need to make sure that when you are presenting a view controller over another view controller that must be in navigation stack otherwise you will get this message in log.

> Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Use the following function to show alert over root view controller

```
 func showAlert(title: String, msg: String, actions:[UIAlertAction]?) {

    var actions = actions
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)

    if actions == nil {
        actions = [UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)]
    }

    for action in actions! {
        alertVC.addAction(action)
    }

    if let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
        rootVC.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("Root view controller is not set.")
    }
}
```

Usage

```
self.showAlert(title: "My App", msg: "your message", actions: nil)
```

You need to use this with your code like this...

```
class SignInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var EmailAddressTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    EmailAddressTextField.delegate = self
    PasswordTextField.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}

@IBAction func LogInButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if (EmailAddressTextField.text != "" && PasswordTextField.text != ""){
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: EmailAddressTextField.text!, password: PasswordTextField.text!) { user, error in
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogInSegue", sender: nil)
            } else {
//                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter a correct email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)
//                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
//                    alert.addAction(action)
//                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                //use like this...
                self.showAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Enter a correct email and password", actions: nil)
            }

        }
    }
}

//###############################################
func showAlert(title: String, msg: String, actions:[UIAlertAction]?) {

    var actions = actions
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)

    if actions == nil {
        actions = [UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)]
    }

    for action in actions! {
        alertVC.addAction(action)
    }

    if let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
        rootVC.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("Root view controller is not set.")
    }
}
//###############################################

}
```

Comment: I think I understand where you're coming from, but as I'm learning Swift at the moment I'm not sure how to implement what you've said. Sorry but could you direct me abit more?

Comment: Sorry just tried it and still getting the same error

Comment: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f8bcf912a00> on <Liftr2.SignInViewController: 0x7f8bcf562230> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Yes I think I used it in the correct way, could you edit using all my code so I can see if it was used correctly?

Comment: Sorry mate, literally pasted that in over my previous code and get the same error... I'm really stumped to what it is

Answer (score 0):

Present it in main activity :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter a correct email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)
   let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
   alert.addAction(action)
   self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
});
```

Comment: Thats not the issue by the way !!